# Trying to toggle a light by mouse clicks

Tags: java

```
public void processLightClick(int row, int col) { 
    states[row][col] = !states[row][col];

    if(states[row][col] = true){
        lights[row][col].setFill(ON_PAINT);
    }
    else if(states[row][col] = false){
        lights[row][col].setFill(OFF_PAINT);
    }
    turns++; 

    System.out.println(row+":"+col);
    status.setText("Turn Number " + turns);
}
```

This is the code I have. I'm trying to get it to toggle states and colors each time a specific square is pressed but the paint stays the same and doesn't toggle the state back and forth when I press the same square twice

Comment: are your `println`s all coming out as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an assignment operator "=" instead of a comparison operator "==" in your if-statement. Try this.

```
public void processLightClick(int row, int col) { 
    states[row][col] = !states[row][col];

    if(states[row][col] == true){
        lights[row][col].setFill(ON_PAINT);
    }
    else if(states[row][col] == false){
        lights[row][col].setFill(OFF_PAINT);
    }
    turns++; 

    System.out.println(row+":"+col);
    status.setText("Turn Number " + turns);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As user2615117 pointed out, you are not using the comparison operator, but the assignment operator.  Here, however, I also would use the [ternary operator](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) to make the code more concise:

```
lights[row][col].setFill((states[row][col] == true) ? ON_PAINT : OFF_PAINT);
```

Another possible improvement would be to have a single array of Light objects which contain both the state and the paint of the light.